# Is ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core MVC the same at present?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to start learning ASP.NET MVC - but just after reading first article I have a question: is ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core MVC totally different and using different code functionalities, OR these two the same now?

I know that .NET Core is a new release from Microsoft, so is it running separate or directly merged to ASP.NET MVC. I am thinking if core is different than we have four types of different applications to develop like ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core MVC.

If I am learning "MVC", does it mean I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC? Does ASP.NET Core MVC have different tutorials, code, projects etc?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 was the last version that will probably ever exist on the original .NET Framework branch, ASP.NET Core is a completely new version and the only one being actively developed on. This is all publicly available information, try to research and read specially Microsoft Docs. Different source code, different supported libraries, different programming models (ASP.NET Core has native support for SPAs for example)...

Comment: Arvind, i have been learning asp.net core mvc, i don't find much difference in between both, about 70% things from ASP.NET MVC5 are same, 30% things they have redesigned and removed. If you have had experience in asp.net mvc then it will take you less than a week to learn asp.net core mvc. Don't hesitate to learn it, just take it on side by side, you will be good. Also if you have got good entity framework experience then you can learn entity framework core in about three days or less than that. all of the concepts are similar.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this question has negative votes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply, Microsoft's naming sucks. There's technically two frameworks: ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, which build upon .NET Framework and .NET Core, respectively.

When Microsoft first attempted to create a "modern" web application platform that adhered to the MVC pattern, it called this new platform "ASP.NET MVC" to distinguish it from previous ASP.NET apps (mostly Web Forms). Then, just to confuse things even more, they later added "ASP.NET Web Api", which was really not a different thing, but just an extension of ASP.NET MVC. The last version of ASP.NET MVC was 5 and the last version ASP.NET Web Api was 2.

Then, Microsoft started working on ASP.NET "vNext", which was really just a code name for a new version of ASP.NET MVC. Initially, the plan was for it to be a new version of MVC, so it also began being referred to as "ASP.NET MVC 6". However, MVC 6 is not a thing and never really existed.

Eventually, it became clear that the direction Microsoft wanted to go with "vNext" was going to require a fundamental shift at the framework level, and work began on .NET Core and ASP.NET Core. Technically, the framework is "ASP.NET Core", period. It's not "ASP.NET Core MVC". The "MVC", "Web Api", and "Razor Pages" terms are simply designations of a particular *style* of ASP.NET Core app. There is no fundamental difference between them, and any ASP.NET Core app can include MVC-style controllers and views, API controllers returning JSON/XML and/or Razor Pages, or any combination thereof.

Long and short, calling it ASP.NET Core is enough. If you're doing something specific, like working with a Razor Page, then you should specify that you're using Razor Pages. Likewise for an API controller, etc., but it's still just ASP.NET Core.